# しゃかいじんの悩みランキング　means?

Tags: translation, meaning

I read a conversation and I don't understand what it talks about !

> A：ちょっとこれみてください。
>
> B：なんですか。
>
> A：しゃかいじんの悩みランキングなんですが。どうおもいますか。
>
> B：やっぱりにんげんかんけいがいちばんおおいですね。よくわかります。わたしのしょくばでも、おなじかもしれません。
>
> C：こころのけんこうもおおいですね。やっぱり。にんげんかんけいにもんだいがあると。こころのびょうきになるかもしれませんね。

especially しゃかいじんの悩みランキング and にんげんかんけいがいちばんおおいですね
and
にんげんかんけいにもんだいがあると 。

Comment: Please also explain what parts you do understand.

Answer (score 2):

しゃかいじんの悩みランキング means "The list of descending order of what troubles member of society have".

にんげんかんけいがいちばんおおいですね means 'it says that they have a trouble about human relationship most".

にんげんかんけいにもんだいがあると means "when they have a trouble about human relationship".

Answer (score 0):

"Member of society" doesn't quite cover the same semantic ground as  しゃかいじん (社会人).   しゃかいじん means someone who is no longer in full-time education, someone who has gone out into the world of work, someone who is responsible for making his or her own living, someone who lives in the real world and has responsibilities (as opposed to someone who is still in the sheltered world of school or university) - almost, in some contexts, "an adult" or "a grown-up".